# Show that $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^N f(x)dx$ exists and relate the limit $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^N f(iy)dy.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the quadrant $\{z : \Re z \geq 0, \Im z \geq 0\}$ satisfying

- $f$ is analytic on $\{z : \Re z>0, \Im z>0\}$;
- $|f(x+iy)|\leq 10e^{−y}$;
- for each $y>0$ we have $f(x+iy)→0$ as $x\to \infty$.

(a) Show that $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^N f(x)dx$ exists and relate the limit $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^N f(iy)dy.$

(b) Prove or disprove: under the given hypotheses $f(x)$ must in fact be absolutely integrable on $[0, ∞).$

I am not so sure how to begin this problem.  I can't think of a way to even bound the first integral appropriately.  All I see is that it is less than $10.$  Some help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the triangles $\Delta_N$ with vertices $0,N,iN$. By Cauchy's integral theorem,

$$\int_{\partial \Delta_N} f(z)\,dz = 0.$$

The estimate $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant 10 e^{-\operatorname{Im} z}$ shows that

$$\int_0^\infty \lvert f(iy)\rvert\,dy < \infty.$$

It thus suffices to see that the integral over the side from $N$ to $iN$ tends to $0$ as $N\to\infty$. For that, fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and $y_0 > 0$ such that

$$\int_{y_0}^\infty 10 e^{-y}\,dy < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}.$$

Let $g_N(y) := f(N-y+iy)$. By the dominated convergence theorem, and the assumption on $f$,

$$\int_0^{y_0} g_N(y)\,dy \to 0.$$

Thus, for all large enough $N$, we have

$$\left\lvert \int_N^{iN} f(z)\,dz\right\rvert < \varepsilon.$$

Put the pieces together to obtain a). For b), I suggest looking for a counterexample.

The given bound suggests that $f$ should contain the factor $e^{iz}$. Now we need to arrange that $f(x+iy) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for every $y$. Dividing by $z$ would do that, but destroy continuity at $0$. But if we shift a little, all is well, thus we can take for example
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z}$$
as a function satisfying the conditions that isn't absolutely integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: What is a possible counterexample for part b)?

Comment: @Nina I've added a counterexample for part b).

Comment: Thank you! The only part I am having trouble seeing is why $|f(x+iy)| \leq 10e^{-y}$. Let's ignore the $10$ for now because $f$ can always be multiplied by $10$. So far I have reduced to $|f(x+iy)| = \frac{e^{-y}}{((x+1)^2 + y^2)^{1/2}}$. Why is this necessarily less than or equal to $e^{-y}$?

Comment: On the first quadrant we have $\lvert 1+z\rvert \geqslant \Re (1+z) \geqslant 1$, hence $$\biggl\lvert \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z}\biggr\rvert = \frac{\lvert e^{iz}\rvert}{\lvert 1+z\rvert} \leqslant \lvert e^{iz}\rvert = e^{-y} \leqslant 10e^{-y}\,.$$

Comment: Right we are in the first quadrant, thanks for the clarification!